# how to put date time image name with my code?

Tags: php

how to put date time in my image upload name code?

```
$allowed_types=array('image/jpg','image/png');

$image_name=$_FILES['thumnail']['name'];

$image_name=$image_name;

$tmp_name=$_FILES['thumnail']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"upload/".$image_name);
```

Comment: Modify `$image_name`, likely using the `date()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$allowed_types=array('image/jpg','image/png');
$image_name=$_FILES['thumnail']['name'];
$array = explode('.', $image_name);
$fileName=$array[0];
$fileExt=$array[1];
$image_name=$fileName."_".time().".".$fileExt;
$tmp_name=$_FILES['thumnail']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"upload/".$image_name);
```